# Checking a number present in a file inputted

Tags: c++, file, input

quick question for a brand new c++ programmer.
how would i go about entering a number into the console, inputting a file and then checking  if the number entered is present in the file?

Comment: Quick Question from a new C++ Programmer :- What have you tried ?

Comment: What do you know? You have to be able to get input from console, open a file, read a stream, and test for presence of one string in another. Which of these cant you do?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

if ( std::find( std::istream_iterator<int>( FileStream),
                std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                number ) !=  std::istream_iterator<int>() )
{
   std::cout << "The number is present in the file" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I wont go about the full code, but it will look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { } //console input
int num = parse(argv[1]); //argv[0] is the path
//parse function is for you to implement
ifstream in("thefile.extension");
int filenum;
in >> filenum;
if(filenum == num) PRESENT
else ABSENT
```